# How to use css transition with bootstrap flexboxes?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, transition

I am trying to add some transition delay to flexbox on hover. But it seems something is wrong with my code.

```css
.flex-fill {  
transition-delay: 250ms !important;
transition:flex 0.5s ease-out !important;
}
.flex-fill:hover {width:60% !important;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="p-2 flex-fill bg-light">Flex item</div>
  <div class="p-2 flex-fill bg-success text-white">Flex item with a lot of content</div>
  <div class="p-2 flex-fill bg-dark text-white">Flex item</div>
  <div class="p-2 flex-fill bg-info text-white">Flex item</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use transition from transition between auto to 60% width. Try changing original width to 100%. and also change transtion style to

```
transition: width 0.5s ease-out !important;
```

```css
.flex-fill {
  transition-delay: 250ms !important;
  transition: width 0.5s ease-out !important;
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-fill:hover {
  width: 160% !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="p-2 flex-fill bg-light">Flex item</div>
  <div class="p-2 flex-fill bg-success text-white">Flex item with a lot of content</div>
  <div class="p-2 flex-fill bg-dark text-white">Flex item</div>
  <div class="p-2 flex-fill bg-info text-white">Flex item</div>
</div>
```